# Non-exclusive Read access to Xodus

Tags: java, xodus

What is the best way to have read-only access a Xodus database (that is already open) that is without Xodus throwing lock error.

The idea is two separate process is accessing the database, one process is with read/write and other is just read only.

Comment: This is the line that throws lock error: final PersistentEntityStore store = PersistentEntityStores.newInstance(xodusRoot + dir);

Answer (score 1):

A single Xodus database can't be shared by multiple processes. From the [Xodus wiki](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Environments#data-environments):

> This method opens an existing database or creates a new database in the directory that is passed as a parameter. It is not possible to share a single database directory between different environments. Any attempt to do this (from within any process, current or not) fails.

There is an open [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-613) to add this functionality.